# Correct logical quantifier notation with greater than/less than relations

Tags: logic, proof-writing, notation, quantifiers

I’m in the middle of some exercises for an intro to proofs class, and want to know if it is possible to write the following:

“For all real $n \geq N$” as $(\forall n \in \mathbb{R} \geq N)$.

If that is incorrect syntax, I’d like to know the correct way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While abbreviations like that may be used informally, they are usually not valid formal syntax. Most commonly, you would write $\forall n\in\mathbb R(n\geq N \to(\dots))$ (or some minor notational variation of this). In fact, the $\forall n\in\mathbb R(\dots)$ is usually itself an informal abbreviation for $\forall n.(n\in\mathbb R \to (\dots))$.

An alternative approach would be to use set builder notation and write $\forall n\in\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x\geq N\}(\dots)$.

What exactly is valid depends on the exact formal notation you're using. I would not be surprised, though, if you haven't been given a clear, comprehensive description of the formal syntax you're supposed to be using. The above is based on common conventions, but conventions vary<sup>1</sup>. If you *have* been given a description of the formal syntax you're supposed to use, you can check yourself whether your translation is a well-formed formula with respect to that syntax.

I do recommend trying to stick to a clear syntax and not use abbreviations, especially undefined abbreviations, at least early on. It is quite common, for example, for people to not have a clear understanding of the abbreviation $\exists x\in\mathbb R.P(x)$.

<sup>1</sup> Eindhoven notation (as illustrated [here](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~carrollm/probs/Papers/Morgan-12.pdf), for example), explicitly covers this pattern of usage, and would lead to something like $(\forall n:\mathbb R\mid n\geq N\bullet(\dots))$.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response. It solved my problem, and I will definitely be referring to this in the future.

Comment: I personally think it is a conceptual 'mistake' to treat restricted quantification as an abbreviation. The reason is not even that the symmetry is lost, i.e. $¬∀x∈S\ ( P(x) ) ≡ ∃x∈S\ ( ¬P(x) )$, but that the right way to think about mathematical objects is in a multi-sorted logic. I know that most texts on logic only deal with standard one-sorted first-order logic, and I know that multi-sorted logic can be encoded in one-sorted logic, but it seems to me that practically speaking it is conceptually better to use sorts to capture typing. Of course, there's nothing wrong with your answer. =)

Answer (score 1):

To add to Derek's answer, the restricted quantification syntax is "$∀x∈S\ ( P(x) )$" or "$∀x:S\ ( P(x) )$", where $S$ is a set/type and "$P(x)$" is a statement about $x$ that is meaningful in the context where $x∈S$. So we cannot have "$∀x∈\mathbb{R}≥N\ ( ... )$". But we can have "$∀x∈\mathbb{R}_{≥N}\ ( ... )$" after we define $\mathbb{R}_{≥N} := \{ x : x∈\mathbb{R} ∧ x≥N \}$. This would be not only rigorous but also immediately understandable. Moreover, this syntax makes certain theorems short and elegant:

> **Strong induction**: $∀m∈\mathbb{N}\ ( ∀k∈\mathbb{N}_{<m}\ ( P(k) ) ⇒ P(m) ) ⇒ ∀m∈\mathbb{N}\ ( P(m) )$ for any property $P$ on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: whoa, I can really appreciate this. probably would save lots of time on my tests as well!